# Why I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python

I have a project with the following hierarchy:

```
create_fresh_databases
 |
 |--src
 |   |
 |   -- configurations
 |       |
 |       |-- config.py
 |       |-- config.xml
 |   -- __init__.py 
 |
 ---- create_fresh_databases.py
```

the `config.py` file contains `Configurations` class

the file `create_fresh_databases.py` looks:

```
from create_fresh_databases.src.configurations.config import Configurations

def main():
   con = Configurations("conf.xml")

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

but I'm getting error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'create_fresh_databases.src'; create_fresh_databases is not a package
```

My IDE is `pycharm`, and I have `python 3.6`

How can I fix it ?

Comment: try `from .src.configurations.config import Configurations`

Comment: Im getting other error: Mo module named '__main__.src'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: can you post full stacktraces? This time it looks to originate from a different place

Answer (score 0):

I think you should organise the package structure like this:

```
Package:
|
|--Configurations:
|  |
|  |--Config.py
|  |      
|  |--Config1.xml
|
|--__init__.py
```

Then you can import it as Package.configurations.config